# How to read multiple connectionstrings in appsetting.json file in .net core api project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have multiple connectionstrings properties for example:-
in AppSetting.json file

```
"connectionstring":{
"connection1":"datasource1";
"connection2":"datasource2";
}
```

i want to read connection string key in controller or service file.
Is it possible in .net Core API ?

Thanks

Comment: I've fixed your tags for you.

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Please clarify more about the question and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

add IConfiguration dependency :

```
 var c1= Configuration.GetConnectionString("connection1");
 var c2= Configuration.GetConnectionString("connection2");
```

Answer (score 0):

First , you have to inject IConfiguration in constructor of controller , you have example in Startup.cs class .

```
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        public Startup(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }
```

```
_config.GetConnectionString("datasource1")
_config.GetConnectionString("datasource2")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the the settings to dependency injection service container for more graceful usage. This is a example for your reference.
Doc: [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration)

Options model

```cs
public class AppSettings
{

    public ConnectionStringOptions ConnectionStrings { get; set; }
}

public class ConnectionStringOptions
{
        public string Connection1 { get; set; }

        public string connection2 { get; set; }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}
        
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.Configure<AppSettings>(this.Configuration);
}
```

Controller.cs

```cs
public class DemoController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly AppSettings appSettings;  

    public DemoController(IOptions<AppSettings> configuration)
    {
       this.appSettings = configuration.Value;
       var connString1 = this.appSettings.Connection1;
       var connString2 = this.appSettings.Connection2;
    }
}
```