# How to read multiple connectionstrings in appsetting.json file in .net core api project with CustomerID?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have customerId:- 1 and 2 and using this customer id i want to filter out my connection string

for example:-

```
"connectionstring":{
"connection_1":"data source"
"connection_2":"data source"
}
```

i want to read connection strings as per my customer id 1 and 2.
Is it possible in .net core webAPI ? i want to access in dbcontext class or controller and change connectionstring dynamically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read multiple connectionstrings in appsetting.json file in .net core api project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67467879/how-to-read-multiple-connectionstrings-in-appsetting-json-file-in-net-core-api)

Answer (score 1):

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "FirstConnection": "Username=...;Password=...;Database=...;Host=...",
    "SecondConnection": "Username=...;Password=...;Database=...;Host=..."
  }
```

in code you can use below code:

```
configuration.GetConnectionString("FirstConnection")
configuration.GetConnectionString("SecondConnection")
```

or if extension method not found use below code:

```
configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")[FirstConnection]
configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")[FirstConnection]
```